# Serializing DataSet to XDocument whitespace issue

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, dataset, xml-serialization

This method takes a DataSet and serializes it to XML.

```
private XDocument GetXDocumentFromDataSet(DataSet dataSet)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8) {Formatting = Formatting.None})
            {
                dataSet.WriteXml(xmlTextWriter);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(memoryStream);
                xmlReader.MoveToContent();
                return XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is that each string field has trailing whitespace.

```
<a>
  <b>Hello               </b>
  <c>World               </c>
</a>
```

It's almost like the width of the column in the database is being used to fill the delta with whitespace.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NVARCHAR()` instead of `CHAR()` as the SQL data-type in your data-model.

Comment: Oops - I didn't build the database - didn't think to look there. Seems obvious now. Thanks!